# Showing partial legend in Highcharts BarChart

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am trying to show a partial legend (like min, medium, max) value fox X and Y axis
and horizontal dashed line in medium of Y axis of HighCharts BarChart.
It is a fairly small graph on a screen (kind of summary of many graphs), but they wanted to make those values visible (I can't fit all).

I am pretty new to it, please help!
Using it with Angular6/7.

TIA,
Oleg.

Comment: I am not sure what do you have in mind by saying "a partial legend". Could you provide some example/image? Maybe are you talking about the plotLines: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/plotlines-dashstyle/

Answer (score 0):

By partial legend I mean that legend will have only 3 points
on both X and Y axis, even when you have 6 or 12 or 24 points
on the chart (show 0, 6, 12 in 12 point X).
And same for Y axis, it would only show Y legend with 3 points,
so around Min, Middle and Max.

Comment: @Sebastian:   By partial legend I mean that legend will have only 3 points on both X and Y axis, even when you have 6 or 12 or 24 points on the chart, should show 0, 6, 12 period in 12 point X). And similarly for Y axis, it would only show Y legend with 3 points, so 0, Middle and Max value.

So if I adjust the sample graph, it should show something like:

200

100 ------------------------------------------

0          1Jan       5Jan     9jan        I hope I answered your question. Can you show me how to do it?

Comment: I used a wrong term, it's not a legend. So I need to display  0, 1/2MaxY and MaxY value on Y axis (0,100,200)    and  [0], [1/2MaxCategory], [MaxCategory] on X, so (1Jan, 5Jan, 9Jan) in that sample. And a plotLine at 1/2MaxY. The reason is that it is a Summary Dashboard, so pretty small chart, it only occupies 3" x 1.25" on the screen. Please help!